# windows.open() with data URI close automatically

Tags: javascript, web, uri

I've a html page that generate a csv with the following code:

```
var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
window.open('data:text/plain,' + encodedUri,'_blank').focus();
```

I'm using firefox in local and it generates correctly a new tab with the data in it, but with firefox or chrome, not in local, the window opens and then close almost immediately (no popup alert triggers)

how may I avoid this and get my file with no problems?

Comment: I am having the same issue, with Firefox. If you have found an answer, please let me know. The site with the issue is https://ayunami2000.github.io

Comment: Hi! I never found a real answer to this problem, this is why I didn't post nothing, I found, thus, a nice workaround, take a look at http://danml.com/download.html, it's a small lib, very effective, it does everything with a simple ***download(csvContent, 'something.txt', 'data:text/plain,');***

Comment: My issue doesn't use downloading; it uses a new window. I could probably use about:blank with injected code, though. Thanks!

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 5):

Apparently one of the filter lists that uBlock Origin uses comes with a rule that unconditionally blocks any data URI popups. https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/issues/2465

Answer (score 4):

This is most probably due to AdBlock extension. I disabled it and that solved the issue for me.

Comment: at the time, I tried on a vanilla firefox too and same thing still happened

Answer (score 0):

All I know is that if you right click and click "Reopen closed tab" after the popup opens, it'll reopen the popup.